# "Started at the bottom" or "Started from the bottom"

Tags: phrase-usage, difference

From wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_Serling#Radio

> Serling started at the bottom, with no writing credits, no published
>   work and no hands-on experience.

But I have always heard

> started from the bottom

and not

> started at the bottom

E.g. in this popular song:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RubBzkZzpUA

Which form is correct?

Comment: It might depend what is being referenced. I might say "started from the bottom of a ladder," but "started at the bottom of the ocean." I'm pretty sure this is one of those cases where there isn't a single "correct" preposition, but a stylistic choice.

Comment: Thanks, which form is more used by the native EN speakers?

Comment: If you are emphasizing starting **from** the bottom, going **to** the top, you'd use _from_, simply to allow for the _from..to_ construct. However, if you are only emphasizing the starting point, with little regard to the rest of the trajectory, then using _at_ might be preferable. This aligns with the Wikipedia article you cited, as the sentence you've quoted here kicks off a long narrative about Serling's early career, before mentioning the start of his professional career four years (and six paragraphs) later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It might depend what is being referenced.
>
> I might say **“started from the bottom of a ladder,”** but **“started at the bottom of the ocean.”**
>
> I'm pretty sure this is one of those cases where there isn't a single “correct” preposition, but a stylistic choice.
>
> ([comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11396/started-at-the-bottom-or-started-from-the-bottom#comment-19389) by [J.R.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113/j-r))

> If you are emphasizing starting from the bottom, going to the top, you'd use **“from,”** simply to allow for the **“from..to”** construct. However, if you are only emphasizing the starting point, with little regard to the rest of the trajectory, then using **“at”** might be preferable.
>
> This aligns with the Wikipedia article you cited, as the sentence you've quoted here kicks off a long narrative about Serling's early career, before mentioning the start of his professional career four years (and six paragraphs) later.
>
> ([comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11396/started-at-the-bottom-or-started-from-the-bottom#comment-19401) by [J.R.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113/j-r))